# How to check if an array is empty or not

Tags: jquery

I am getting the response in this format

```
[
    {
        "name": "Large, 100 Ml",
        "image": "http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
        "quantity": "1",
        "price": "75",
        "toppings": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Regular, 50 Ml",
        "image": "http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
        "quantity": "1",
        "price": "75",
        "toppings": [
            {
                "name": "Regular, 50 Ml0",
                "value": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For some elements the toppings are empty and for some they may contain values .

How can i check if the toppings array is empty or not ??

I have tried toppins.length < 0 and toppins!='[]'

But nothing worked , could anybody please tell me how to check if the array is empty or not null .

```
for (var j = 0; j < products.length; j++) 
       {
        var itemname = products[j].name
        var image = products[j].image
        var quan = products[j].quantity
        var price = products[j].price
       var toppins =  products[j].toppings

          if (itemname != 'undefined' && itemname!='') 
            {

        if (toppins.length < 0) 
        {
         alert('here'+itemname);
        }
           }
               }
```

Comment: `toppins.length < 0` is checking if there are less than 0 items in it. Should be equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the length

```
if (toppins.length)
```

`0` is falsy

Or `toppins.length == 0` for empty

Comment: Thanks , i missed equals to :)

Answer (score 0):

Just doing `< 0` as you suggested in your question would fail, because an empty array has zero length.  To test is the array is empty you'd be wanting:

```
if (toppings.length === 0) { ... }
```

since `.length` cannot possibly give a negative answer.

This can also (but IMHO shouldn't) be written as:

```
if (!toppings.length) { ... }
```

This is perfectly legal and a common idiom, but it relies on type-casting the `length` property to a boolean, whereas the `=== 0` test is far more explicit and need not perform any casts.

Comment: `less than or equal` would not be necessary -- just the equal.

Comment: I guess that's what I get when writing answers tired and unwell :(

Comment: @Alnitak: Get better soon! (The downvotes seemed rather harsh to me, fwiw.)